# My Firestore query always takes just over 20 seconds. Is there a hidden timeout or similar?

Tags: python, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having an issue with a Firestore query taking a long time to run.

There are currently 2 records in the Firestore collection, but this query is always taking 20-21 seconds.

This suggests to me that there is a sleep or a timeout that lasts 20 seconds somewhere.

```py
    start_first_query = time.time()
    db = firestore.client()
    doc_ref = db.collection('users').document(uid)
    doc = doc_ref.get(['my_value'])
    doc_dict = doc.to_dict()
    print(f'first query took: {time.time() - start_first_query}')
```

Example outputs:

```
first query took: 20.2761070728302
first query took: 20.213554859161377
first query took: 20.25418519973755
```

I also have a second slightly more complex query with an `in` operator, which has a similar just over 20 second execution time. Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening?

Happy to share more details if required, as the code I have provided is basically straight from the documentation.

TLDR; I successfully wrote code to extract data from the DB. It always hangs for 20 seconds but I normally get sub 1-second latency when doing similar queries.

Edit: I have rerun with `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`, and there is definitely a 20-second wait at the start of `doc_ref.get(['my_value'])` as I wait 20 seconds, then the following debug logs appear.

```bash
>  DEBUG:google.auth.transport.requests:Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
>  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
>  DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

Comment: If you want to know what the library is doing, you can always see the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore).

Comment: Thanks, @DougStevenson - I've had a look and can see the error has to do with a call to `self._client._firestore_api.batch_get_documents` but I cannot seem to find the correct definition for this function, so I gave up on that.

Answer (score 1):

From your logs it looks like the time is spend retrieving authentication. If I run the same code I get this output:

```py
import time

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Application Default credentials are automatically created.
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
db = firestore.client()

start_first_query = time.time()
db = firestore.client()
doc_ref = db.collection("users").document("XXX")
doc = doc_ref.get(["displayName"])
doc_dict = doc.to_dict()
print(f"first query took: {time.time() - start_first_query}")
```

```bash
first query took: 0.31332993507385254
```

Your code doesn't show how you get authentication, but this is likely the bottleneck. You can try setting up default credentials (which is what I did) using the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#how-to